# Why was my question deleted?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

**My thoughts on my question being deleted**

I believe the post below is clearly ON topic. I'm not asking for anyone to debug the situation, merely asking for a recommendation for a compatible card because I'm unfamiliar with this specific technology.

I would have loved to reach out to @ArtOfCode who closed it to find out why he thought it's off topic, as he just closed it without decent feedback.

For brevity here is the question summarised. I do not feel that he read it, and just blindly closed the question.

I need a hardware recommendation for a M.2 Module for this motherboard.. which one would be suitable (as the current one I bought does not work due to the reasons explained in my question)?

---

**Original Link**
https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13675/m-2-wifi-module-confusion

**Original content**

> **Problem:**
>
> I have recently built a new gaming PC for myself it's about 4/5 months old currently. The motherboard is a Asrock Extreme4 x570. I would like to install a WIFI module into it.
>
> **Context**
>
> I'm not familiar with the specification etc of these modules, but I did some R&D then discovered I need a 2230 module... I then ordered the following gigabyte GC-CI22M_A module... it installed fine... but it does not want to work, doesn't matter what I try... installing & re-installing the drivers, went through the bios with a fine toothed comb... and I could not find anything.
>
> I then discovered that there is something like CNVi... and that there is a difference (I think) between it and the M.2 base cards (excuse my terminology... again, I'm a noob)
>
> I have discovered on other Asrock boards that they do say does not support CNVi but its not the case on this board... but I'm starting to think they might have omitted that detail in the spec document by accident.
>
> I have reached out to Asrock support, but they have not responded and its driving my insane.
>
> **Question:**
>
> What do I need to search for to buy a compatible module? Or how do I ensure I don't buy another piece of scrap PCB. I live in South Africa, so I have limited options at the moment... but I will link what I think might be viable to get.
>
> This seems like a good option 1 from a trusted store here here. I was thinking I can remove the module from the card & use the existing antennae cabled from my previous purchase?
>
> Option 2 Module on its own (although.. I'm not familiar with this specific store... but that's a topic for another forum)
>
> Any advice in just helping me clear up WHAT type of module I need to search for will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite: _why_ do you believe that's on-topic?

Comment: This forum's name is Hardware Recommendations? I (still don't know jack about these WIFI module cards) I did some R&D... then provided 2 links of cards I believe are suitable... I asked a question on here hoping someone could recommend or endorse a specific card or type of card... since it seems that there are nuances..

Comment: If thats not the point of this site... this name is WAAAAAAYYY off point.

Comment: So the only reason you think it's on topic is because the name is "Hardware Recommendations"?

Comment: But second to the above... I know you're a big mod on SO... and you probably go through a ton of post & reviews on here & other forums... I thank you for that (even voted for you in past elections). But sometimes just a blind kill & close, does not help or provide any clarity on the topic. I've seen-it happen time and time again that mods or high rep users just throw their weight around... and this just 100% felt like that. Sorry if I misinterpreted the intent or the topic of this forum.. again the name lead me to believe this is the place to ask. :)

Comment: Protip: always read the [help] before you post on a new site... "Hardware Recommendations" is a broad name, but we couldn't really fit "Specific Hardware Recommendations Given Strict Requirements And Specification" in :)

Comment: The thing is I read another post here on meta specifically asking for clarity on what’s allowed... and per my understanding my quest falls well within that bounds... I’d go as far as to say... broad name = allow broad questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for in that question falls in the "tech support" or "general advice" categories, both of which are off-topic here. This site provides recommendations of specific hardware when given detailed requirements and specification of the required hardware - we can't help with identifying *what kind* of hardware you need, nor with "how should I go about this" kind of questions.

Have a read of [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Again I don’t think you read my question. My question falls within all the parameters of what you described here... I specified specific hardware... maybe my fault was with doing too much research? Maybe if I just stated that I have this specific motherboard... what module will work with it? Vs which of these will work with it?

Comment: Anyhow... I’ll leave it at that... All the best on this forum. I’ll go ask somewhere like redit perhaps?

Comment: I... don't see how you're asking for a recommendation of specific hardware, @Rohan. Your questions seem to be "What do I need to search for" (general advice), "can I remove the module and use the antenna" (tech support), and "clear up what type of module to look for" (general advice, requirements-too-broad). I don't see a "recommend me one of X type of hardware, with A, B, and C requirements".

Comment: Sorry. But the question is not that. I have added some context purely to explain what I have tried (coming from SO... I assumed that would be good... it might have added the the frustration/ confusion) but you’ll see if you read the question at the end, the question is what type of card do I need to buy, my phasing might be different than how you’d have liked it, but Every person has their own writing style. Apart from that I also I just linked a few cards I know I can get in my country from what I could find online to limit the results / make the recommendations easier...

Comment: So... what _is_ the question, @Rohan? There are no other sentences ending in question marks or even remotely looking like a question in your post, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Sigh... you’re totally missing the question man. No point in debating this further. Since you have the power and this is the internet. I do feel you’re being unfair, especially since you’re not comprehending the core of the question. (No insult intended, maybe it is just what it is. Language barrier, colloquialisms i might have used, etc). Like I said I’ll go find another forum rather. Thank you for you time.

Comment: I'm not trying to be unfair, @Rohan, I just can't see where you ask for us to recommend you some specific hardware - you seem to be asking other things, as far as I can see. If you can point it out to me, perhaps there's a way to clarify your question and get it reopened.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same situation. As you can see below.

[image]

My question was a pre-purchase question.
My question was looking for specific product recommendations
My question was a request to get advice so that I could make a decision on what products to purchase.

Nothing to do with tech support, or a step by step instructions etc.

Having the item closed off provided ZERO means to ask why and as you can see it does fit into the 'Hardware Recommendations'.

This obviously isn't an answer, but I hope this will lead to the changes required as other Stack Overflow area actually helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I agree... Your question sounds fair enough to me as a hardware question. In theory, had I seen, and known about an answer... I could have summarized that what you're asking. Obviously you don't know of a specific device, but from your perspective, you suspect it to be a hardware item that might resolve this and again, prompting you to ask this here the hardware forum. Unrelated. I eventually found out the difference between the card types in my question... but it could have been easily pointed out by someone knowledgeable on here. Anyhow.. no point in feeling bad about it I guess.